# Christmas-ifying seafood linguine

Tags: substitutions, seafood, seasonal

How would you modify seafood linguine to give it a holiday twist? I am cooking and some of my conservative guests are in shock after hearing the menu. How can I mollify them?

Comment: I'm no professional, but if you'd like to give it a holiday twist, maybe add some candy cane bits inside? If it won't go well, you can always serve a side meal that is originally "Christmas-ified".

Comment: Dress the seafood wirh santa costumes

Comment: I don't understand what would be shocking about seafood linguine, nor why it is not seen as "seasonal."  Unless there are health concerns, give them some strong egg nog, and make the best damn seafood linguini you can.

Comment: but think twice before putting candy cane bits in.

Comment: Make a note not to invite these people next year, if you can at all avoid it..

Comment: These complaints are truly bizarre, IMO. Pasta and seafood is literally a Christmas Eve classic — definitely an Italian-American tradition, at the very least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it a red&green linguini?

There are a number of ways to color pasta, or sauce - some might be natural, some might be commercially available.  Like using spinach and tomato flavored past, or one could use food dye, or modify the sauce recipe (which can start out ranging from marinara red to pesto green to white sauce, depending on recipe), or add or modify toppings (flakes of red n green bell peppers, or tomato or broccoli, etc).

It might even work with just one modification, ie, green and white, red and white, green and red, are all Christmas-ish color combos.

I don't know what your recipe is, or what colors might already be present (based on ingredients, etc) but it might not be too tricky a change with a bit of planning.

Answer (score 2):

You could use fresh chopped green herbs and some minced red pepper as a Christmas color themed garnish.

Answer (score 1):

We might need to know where you live & what you can get hold of at the last minute.

I'd say if you live inside 45° of the Equator, or South of it - ie, it's likely to be warm even if not actually sunny, you could possibly get away with some quick last-minute trimmings - a holly leaf, a gingerbread reindeer... anything you can find at the local supermarket.

If you live North of that, anywhere people wouldn't consider snow at Xmas to be outside the realms of possibility (even if it only actually happens once a decade) the I think you may have mistaken the word 'conservative' for 'traditional' & have an uphill struggle, which I'm tempted to think could only be cured by turning your linguine into a starter & setting up something with at least a sprout, a carrot & hopefully some kind of potato next to it for main.

At worst, grab a slice of turkey breast & turn it into turkey & seafood linguine.

Comment: The linguine was indeed a starter, and I should have said 'traditional'.